# Altering base Odoo field via XML file

Tags: odoo

I am trying to edit the `default_code` field on the `product.product` model. I am attempting to make it so the field is no longer copied when duplicating a record. This is the XML record in my module:

```xml
<record id="product.field_product_product_default_code" model="ir.model.fields">

      <field name="copy" eval="False"/>

</record>
```

When I import the module, I get an import error. If I comment out this record, the rest of my module imports without an issue, so I believe this is causing the problem. Is it not possible to alter a base field in this manner?

Comment: Never really seen it through xml, usually you edit a .py for doing that

Comment: Yea, I'm currently on Odoo Saas, so can only use XML in my module.

Comment: Not sure how mandatory is to put that on a module, but did you try with an update from postgresql?

Comment: I'm using Odoo Saas. Do not have access to the database or .py files.

Comment: Sorry!, I Will try to acomplish it and post an answer to help if i can

Comment: i tryied you code error is: `Properties of base fields cannot be altered in this manner! `  i don't now if it's the same case in Saas. and even using developer mode cannot do that same error message.

Comment: Thanks @CherifOdoo. Can you tell me the steps you took to produce that error?

Comment: i tried your code in a local version 10.0.  got the error then i tried to do it using UI by  developer mode this modification is not allowed i think. what you mean by step you mean using UI?

Comment: When you say you "tried my code", do you mean you put it in a data file for a module and tried to import that module? You got that error when importing?

Comment: i'm not using Saas i'm using normal version i tried to upgrade my model and i get that error and i think is the same thing for you